# a variant of Basel problem (including a real number shift)

Tags: sequences-and-series

is a solution of this infinite series known?

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n-f)^2}$

where  $f$ is a generic real number (but cannot be integer)

Thank you for your help

Comment: I would guess almost all positive real numbers are possible solutions, apart from those of the form $\displaystyle \sum_{n=k}^{\infty} \frac1{n^2}$ for some positive integer $k$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function#Series_representation

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I am looking for a solution for a fixed f

Answer (score 1):

We have:

$$ -\gamma+\frac{d}{dx}\log\Gamma(x+1) = -\gamma+\psi(x+1) = \sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+x}\right) $$
hence by differentiating both sides with respect to $x$:
$$ \psi'(1-f) = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{(n-f)^2}.$$